# File in executable jar cannot be found when running on AWS EC2

Tags: jar, amazon-ec2

I have a .jar file executing on a aws ec2 instance which contains the following code:

```
List<String> lines = FileUtils.readLines(new File("googlebooks-eng-all-1gram-20120701-k"));
```

the file exists in projectname/res and also in /projectname directly. I included /res in the build path. Also I see that the file exists inside the jar file at the root if I export the .java file in eclipse.
If I run the jar localy on my pc it works fine. But if I run it on a ec2 instance it says:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File 'googlebooks-eng-all-1gram-20120701-k' does not exist
```

How can that be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your PC it is reading from the actual file on the filesystem - that is what `new File` means - a file on the filesystem.

To access a resource in a jar file you need to call `getResourceAsStream` or something similar instead.